# I have four servos connected to an arduiono uno and I cannot control them

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

[image: Image of my setup]I am making a simple bipedal robot. I have four 9g servos connected to my uno. Whenever I try to even do the simplest command, like move right foot 45 degrees it does not work properly. I have tried on my second Uno and i have the same result.

My program for testing the servos:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;

void setup(){
myservo.attach(6);
}

void loop(){
 myservo.write(45); 
}
```

Each servo wire is attached to a breadboard where they all share power and ground from the arduino. Each servo wire then has another wire going to pins 3,5,6 and 9.

Does anyone know what the problem is and what I can do? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's your wiring. Maybe it's the servos. Maybe four servos are too many for a single Uno to power. Please show your schematic.

Comment: Powering one micro-servo through the +5V pin of the Uno should be OK, and I would expect the program you posted to work. Powering four of them may be too much, especially if they are somewhat loaded.

Comment: Please let us know how the +V and 0V connections to the servos are made. Ideally they should be connected to an external battery or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Arduino is not capable of powering four servos. Power them externally, but make sure the ground of the Arduino and servos is connected.

Comment: This has done nothing. Also I believe an arduino can power four servos but I tested it anyway.

Comment: Could you share your current setup of the servos and the Arduino?

Comment: Have you even tried powering the servos externally?

Comment: I don't think this answer should have been marked down - the arduino's regulator really isn't suitable for directly supplying power to that many servos as Len has said, partly due to electrical noise etc.

Comment: @Len yes I have tried powering the servos externally

Comment: With the grounds of the servos and Arduino connected? Because then I really don't know why it wouldn't work, unless your Arduino is already fried or something.

Comment: Keep in mind that you may also be limited by the USB power supply.  By definition that power source can cut you off at 500mA.  Also, servo current demand is hard to figure out.  As others have pointed out, you should be able to control 1 "unloaded-small" servo using the Arduino Uno's on board linear 5 volt regulator.  However, from your picture, you are only using the USB port.  This mean that you are not using the internal 5 volt regulator and that you are relying directly on what ever your are plugged into to provide 5 volts.  continued in next comment...

Comment: ... So, given you have swapped around Arduino Uno boards and servos (you have swapped around servos, right?),  you should now swap out the USB power source.  Note: According to [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf) schematic, there is a 500mA fuse in line with the USB 5 volt power line on the Arduino Uno.  So be careful not to exceed this.

Comment: I strongly advise against using the Arduino Uno to power your servos. The maximum current of the VCC and GND pins is 200 mA according to their [official documentation](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations). You can go over a bit, but 500 mA? That's just asking for a failure in your Arduino device.

Power the servos from an external power source, connect the grounds of the servos and the Arduino and you're good to go.

Comment: OK thanks everyone but I am still unsure how to properly power the servos externally, could you explain how. Secondly what power should I supply? 9v?

Comment: Depends on your servo. Mostly it's 4.8V, but sometimes 6 or 12. Too much volts also fries the servos, so you need a voltage regulator or a 5V external power source (like a phone charger).

Then you just split the VCC to the VIN of the Arduino and the servos. Then you connect all the grounds. That's basically all. But make sure you have the right voltage for your servos, you can find this information in the datasheet.

Comment: @Len: The 200 mA you are quoting is the absolute maximum for the Vcc and GND pins of the ATmega328P. It is **not a limit of the Arduino**. The current you source from the Arduino's +5V _does not go_ through the ATmega's Vcc pin, thus that limit is irrelevant.

Comment: You're completely right. I didn't even know that. A quick search shows that the max values are between 500mA and 1A. So, it might actually be possible to power multiple servos, albeit it's still a risk.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the Arduino cannot drive 4 servos - my experience is that it can have problems powering one if you try to move it too often due to the voltage drop caused by the high current consumption.  When you move a servo the power consumption rises considerably.  A large (220uF or more) capacitor near he servo can help, but even so, by far the best option is to supply the servos from a separate supply.

If the Uno resets when you try to move the servos (especially multiple times per second) then the power supply is most likely your culprit.